# Apply a diff on a specific file from a merge commit in git

Tags: git

I am doing a rebase that includes a merge conflict that I already resolved in a merge commit in another branch.  Is there a way to apply that resolution on the respective file from the merge commit?  Basically, given a merge commit, I want to apply the diff of the +'s and -'s from the second column over a specific file.  I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little late now, but using [git rerere](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rerere.html) can make this much easier if it comes up a lot.

At this point, what I would try first is a `git cherry-pick -n -m [1 or 2] [merge commit SHA1]`, then only commit the changes to the one file (by resetting the other ones or whatever), then do your rebase.

Comment: I *do* have rerere on.  It didn't do anything, assumedly because the merge contained a bunch of other changes too (?)

Comment: `cherry-pick` doesn't seem to work.  It just tells me `fatal: Your index file is unmerged.` (because of the merge conflicts from the rebase).  Didn't know about the `-m` option, though.  +1 for that.

Comment: @asmeurer, you're probably right that the conflicts look just different enough.  You have to abort your rebase before doing the cherry-pick.

Comment: Well that doesn't help me any.  I'm trying to fix the merge conflict in the rebase.

Comment: @asmeurer, yeah, but if you apply the changes before the rebase, the conflict should be simpler to resolve, in theory at least.  Another option is to save a `git diff` to a file and manually apply it with a patch utility.

Comment: I suppose.  I would then have to go back in and squash the commits, but it would work.

Comment: By the way, I just did it manually, but I am still interested it there would have been a way to do it.